# Using Mongoose and Node to find if an email address is in the database, then saving it to another user.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a route that is used to add a friend for a user. The criteria are as follows.

1) If the person exists in the friends list, return "Is already a friend"
2) If not, then check the entire database for the friend, if not found then add to the users "friends" field with only email. If they are found, then take the id, username and email and save it as an object in the "friends" field of the users document.

Im going back and forth on the best way to do this, any thoughts?

```
router.post("/user/friends/:id", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
//finds user by ID only returns friends and groups
User.findById(req.user.id, 'friends', function(user){
    //get an array of just email addresses from friends
    var exists;
    var emails = user.friends.map(function(friendsEmail){
        return friendsEmail.email;
    }, function(done){
        var emailExists = checkForIfExists(emails, user.friends.email);
        if (emailExists === true){
            //Tell user that the emails exists
            res.send("You are already friends!")
            return exists = true;
        } else {
            //search for your friends email address in the db.
            User.find({email: user.friends.email},'username _id email', function(person){
            var addFriend = {
                username: person.username,
                _id: person._id,
                email: person.email
            };

            addFriend.save();
                return exists = false;
            } );

            //Save the user to the database in the friends field.
            //Return to user that it was saved.
        }
    });
    //Will return true or false based on the .some method in the function

    if (exists === true) {
        res.send("You are already friends, homes");
    } else {
        res.send()
    }
    //This checks to see if something exists in an array
    function checkForIfExists(array, item){
        return array.some(function(exists){
            return item === exists;
        });
    }
})
});
```

FYI, isLoggedIn is a middleware to ensure people are logged in before anything happens. `User` is my collection name for Users, also this is mid write so Im not done but it should give you an idea of what Im thinking.